# Write text inside a < div > from an external function. PHP

Tags: php, html

Sorry if I have done wrong , is my first question on StackOverflow.

I want to write the value of var after doing several checks that are within the functions and as a result if everything is okey want to print the variables in a particular div. I have created three different div , one to display errors , one to show var and other one for the form.

What I Do That IS THIS:
https://mega.co.nz/#!3EQGQSAL!94ao1u6UhARYaYdjJzfFqY6ln1oPyO9JQ4_ElT7WEkA

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Agenda Alex Ventura</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        #errores {
            display: block;
            background-color: grey;
            border-color: red;
            border-top-style: double;
            border-right-style: double;
            border-bottom-style: double;
            border-left-style: double;

        }
        #contactos {
            margin-top: 20px;
            background-color: aquamarine;
        }
        #formulario{
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="errores">
        <?php
        if (!(isset($_POST['enviar']))) {
            //Primera vez
            $nombre = "";
            $telefono = "";
        } else {
            if (errores()) {
                //Segunda o siguientes veces con error
                $nombre = "";
                $telefono = "";
            } else {
                //Todo ok
                $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
                $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
                imprimir_datos();
            }
        }

        function errores() {
            $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
            if ((empty($nombre)) || (empty($telefono))) {
                echo "Los campos de usuariio y telefono no pueden estar vacíos";
                return true;
            }
            if (strlen($telefono) < 9) {
                echo "El telefono debe tener 9 digitos " . strlen($telefono);
                return true;
            }
            if (strlen($telefono) > 9) {
                echo "El telefono debe tener 9 digitos " . strlen($telefono);
                return true;
            }
            $expresion = '[0-9]';
            if (preg_match($expresion, $telefono) != true) {
                echo "El telefono debe tener solo numeros " . ($telefono);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div id="contactos">
        <?php
       function imprimir_datos() {
                $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
                $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
                echo "Nombre: $nombre, Telefono: $telefono</br>";

        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div id="formulario">
        <form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> method="POST">
            Nombre : <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo "$nombre"; ?>"/>
            Telefono:    <input type="text" name="telefono" value="<?php echo "$telefono"; ?>"/>`enter code here`
            <input TYPE="submit" VALUE="Enviar" name="enviar"/> 
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

https://mega.co.nz/#!CA5TmCQJ!utWGpH7PZwpPcHbDK3eTG6JMuTRz_Z6KKAFWtbqPm1o

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: having a hard time understanding what exactly you are trying to do. I understand your code since I personally am Spanish but even then I still dont understand what you want.

Comment: i've check the image what he uplodaed. the problem was, it echoes this error message "El telefono debe tener solo numeros", because he doesn't add delimiters to his pattern.

Comment: The problem is That imprimir_datos () function does not print the var Data Within < div id = "Contacts "> , Data Within The prints < div id = " errors "> and I want to print Inside < div id = "Contacts ">

Comment: anyway, this design is bad. when you call the `imprimir_datos` functon, it won't display in div with id contactos, just you placed there the function.

Answer (score 1):

oh, i see now. Patterns needs delimiters.

change this:

```
if (preg_match($expresion, $telefono) != true) {
```

to this:

```
if (preg_match("/" . $expresion . "/", $telefono) != true)
```

And for the printing the details, try this. Move the function outside from the div, and call it within the div.

```
<div id="contactos"><?php imprimir_datos(); ?></div>

<?php
function imprimir_datos() {
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    echo "Nombre: $nombre, Telefono: $telefono</br>";
}
?>
```